# How to play video in ios6

Tags: ios, xcode, video, ios6

I'm confused about:

MPMoviePlayerViewController and MPMoviePlayerController

what is the best way to play a video locally in ios6?

this is my code

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @ "17" OfType: @ "mov"]];

     MoviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                     initWithContentURL: url];
     [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated: MoviePlayer];
     [moviePlayer.moviePlayer play];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @ selector (moviePlayerPlaybackStateChanged :) name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object: nil];
}


-(void)moviePlayerPlaybackStateChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {


}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MPMoviePlayerViewController is for playing fullscreen video and is used mostly on the phone.

MPMoviePlayerController can be used for embedded video, ie not full screen on any of the iPads. You need to pull an empty view onto your scene in storyboard and give it the desired size. Then, in code, place the movieplayer in that subview. The first part of your code should be in viewDidLoad;

```
//movieplayer initialization
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"videoName" ofType:@"m4v"];
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
[moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone]; // for custom controls, for default controls you can leave this line out.
```

This part goes in viewWillAppear;

```
moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne; // for looping
[moviePlayer.view setFrame: self.videoSuper.bounds]; 
[self.videoSuper addSubview: moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[moviePlayer play];
```

where videoSuper is the subview added in storyboard. Be sure to hook it up correctly;

```
//in .h
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *videoSuper;
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it does not work for me for some reason. I created a single view project, with xib but no storyboard. Added a UIView and connected it with the file owner. All i see is a white screen, and no audio. Any help or suggestions on what i might have done wrong? Is there a better way to run videos today that i dont know of??

Comment: Did you name the outlet connected to the view? I wrote this before I knew much about naming conventions. What I am calling videoSuper should be called videoView or something similar and it should be an IBOutlet in your h file that gets connected to the view in your NIB. (I use storyboards so the details are up to you.) In storyboard you would right click on the view in the storyboard and drag to the header file in the area where properties are declared and a popup will give you a chance to name it. Name it videoView and then your Controller will have a property you can refer to in code.

Comment: [self.videoView addSubview: moviePlayer.view];

Comment: @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *videoView;

Comment: Why the videoSuper?  Can't the moviePlayer's view be added directly to self.view?

Comment: The purpose of videoSuper is to have a representation of the video in StoryBoard, for design and convenience.