# Attempt to present MPMoviePlayerViewController while a presentation is in progress

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, viewdidlayoutsubviews

I get warning described in title and I've found that this is as a result of calling `viewDidLayoutSubviews` multiple times.

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"wq" ofType:@"mp4"]];
self.playerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.playerController];
[self.playerController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

self.playerController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
self.playerController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
self.playerController.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
self.playerController.moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;

[self.playerController.view setFrame:self.movieView.bounds];
[self.movieView addSubview:self.playerController.view];

[self.playerController.moviePlayer play];
}
```

I have also tried using above code in `(void) loadView` but the result was the same.
I also have some buttons in the storyboard which I don't want to miss them.
Could anyone help me to have only one MPMoviePlayerViewController?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Finally I solved the issue using this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040862/how-to-play-video-in-ios6). Thanks timquinn!